# play a sound using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I am trying to play a sound on event using javascript

tried this

```
<object height="100" width="100" data="sounds/cash.wav" id="cash"></object>

var thissound= document.getElementById("cash");
thissound.play();
```

and it worked. the thing is , I don't my element to show on the browser, so I tried

```
<object height="0" width="0" data="sounds/cash.wav" id="cash"></object>
and even
<object height="100" width="100" data="sounds/cash.wav" id="cash" style="display:none"></object>
```

and I got an error in the JS telling me that the element is null..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
<object height="100" width="100" data="sounds/cash.wav" id="cash" style="visibility: hidden; white-space: nowrap;"></object>
```

to hide it.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can wrap the `object` element in a block, and hide the block.